# How to use CSOM, SOAP or Rest API to detect anonymous views of list items for a List?

Tags: list, rest, csom, soap, anonymous-access

Let's say I have a SharePoint site with anonymous view enabled for the entire website
[image: anonymous access of website]

But I have a List that breaks role inheritance.

How do I use CSOM, Rest API or SOAP API to detect if a List has anonymous access enabled?

`View Items  -  View items in lists, documents in document libraries, view Web discussion comments, and set up alerts for lists.`

[image: anonymous access of list]

Answer (score 0):

Only way I can figure out how to get this information is from the SOAP API.

It seems like the only thing in the entire SharePoint object model that changes when I update that field is `AnonymousPermMask` from the Lists.asmx service.

This does not appear to be available from any of the apis except the Soap API? Why isn't this available? I created a [uservoice about this](https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329214-sites-and-collaboration/suggestions/42197563-make-sure-everything-that-is-available-from-the-so):

`AnonymousPermMask="68719546465"` - When checked.
`AnonymousPermMask="0"` - When not checked.

Request to get it:

`/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx`

- Header: `SOAPAction: http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/GetList`
- Header: `Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8`
- Request body:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Body>
        <GetList xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">
            <listName>{SHAREPOINT_LIST_GUID_HERE}</listName>
        </GetList>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```